# Topological properties of symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrices, compactness, connectedness, positive-definite

Let $S$ be the set of all symmetric positive definite matrices of size $n\times n$. Which of the following statements are true?

(a) $S$ is closed in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.
 (b) $S$ is connected in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.
 (c) $S$ is compact in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Only the option (a) & (b) are right. I guess that it is not bounded so (c) is not true. Am I correct?

Comment: Can you prove it is not bounded? Do a particular case with $\,n=2\,$ and check you can easily  construct a symmetric pos. def. matrix with as high a norm as wanted (I'm guessing you're taking the euclidean one in $\,\Bbb M_n(\Bbb R)\leq \Bbb R^{n^2}\,$ ...)

Comment: a is false @etuku

Answer (score 7):

It is not just connected, in fact it is path connected. for $A,B$ such matrices we have $x^TAx\ge 0$, $x^TBx\ge 0$ so  for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we get $x^T[\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B]x\ge 0$.

Comment: can you confirm me that is it closed or not? i think it is closed not fully sure.

Comment: It is the inverse image of $0$ by the map $f(A) \mapsto (a_{i,j} - a_{j,i})_{i\neq j}$ which is clearly continuous.

Comment: I must have somehow read only half of the question. The set of positive definite symmetric Matrices is not closed. To see this, $\lambda I$ is in $S$ for $\lambda > 0$ but not for $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: how it is closed can u plzz explain @etuku??? I got  a counter example take a sequence of matrices ${A_n}$ whose diagonal elements are $1/n$ every thing else is 0...Then this will converge to a zero matrix..

Answer (score 2):

As La Belle Noiseuse said, $S$ is a convex set; $S$ is also open in a vector space of dimension $n(n+1)/2$; thus $S$ is homeomorphic to the open ball of $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$ for an arbitrary norm.

EDIT for @ Sahiba Arora. The property "$A$ is heomorphic to a bounded set" gives no information about the fact that $A$ is bounded or not. Indeed, the open ball of $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$ is homeorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$.

Here $S$ is not closed (consider the sequence $(\dfrac{1}{k}I_n)_k$) and is not bounded (consider the sequence $(kI_n)_k$).

Comment: Then $S$ must be bounded? @DonAntonio mentioned in the comments that $S$ can't be bounded.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.