# set of all symmetric non-negative definite matrices are closed or not

Tags: general-topology, matrices

Can anyone tell me please that set of all symmetric non-negative definite matrices are closed or not in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with usual topology

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282122/let-s-be-the-set-of-all-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-which-of-the-foll/282125#282125

Answer (score 10):

- If $S$ is a matrix and $x\in\Bbb R^n$, the map $f_x\colon S\mapsto x^tSx$ is linear hence continuous.
- Let $S^+_n(\Bbb R)$ the set of symmetric non-negative definite matrices. Then 
  $$S^+_n(\Bbb R)=\bigcap_{x\in\Bbb R^n}f_x^{-1}([0,+\infty)).$$
- As $f_x^{-1}([0,+\infty))$ is closed in $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$, $S_n^+(\Bbb R)$ is closed as an arbitrary intersection of such sets.

Comment: I am confused by the answer of you and the link given by panu.please guide me properly

Comment: So, what don't you understand?

Comment: they give different answer.there says that it is not closed

Comment: Positive definite is not the same thing as non-negative definite (which means $x^tSx\geqslant 0$ for all $x$).

Comment: I can't understand how $S^+_n(\Bbb R)=\bigcap_{x\in\Bbb R^n}f_x^{-1}([0,+\infty)).$? Please explain.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo I have a problem about intersection..Please clear it.

Comment: @Panja.S.  $A$ belongs to the intersection iff $f_x(A)\geqslant 0$ for each $x$ iff x^tAx\geqslant 0$ for each $x$, which is exactly the definition of non-negative definite matrix.